# How can I get the file id if I use the file_save_data function?

Tags: 8, entities, files

I will be adding new media files in D8 programmatically, how do I determine what the fid should be for each one? also how do i put the actual file contents into the media type?
this is my code

```
$file_name=$file_info['file_name'];
  $file = file_get_contents($fullpath."/".$file_name); // string
 $filesaved = file_save_data($file, 'public://'.$file_directory_name."/".$file_info['file_name')',FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
  $fid = ???; 
  $static_media = Media::create([
      'bundle' => 'document',
      'uid' => '1',
      'langcode' => Language::LANGCODE_DEFAULT,
      'status' => Media::PUBLISHED,
      'your_image_field_name_here' => [
        'target_id' => $fid,
        'alt' => t('foo'),
        'title' => t('bar'),
      ],
    ]);
    $static_media->save();
```

Comment: The function file_save_data() returns a file entity. So i suppose you need $filesaved->fid->value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
$filesaved = file_save_data($file, 'public://'.$file_directory_name."/".$file_info['file_name']), 'FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE');
$fid = $filesaved->id;
```

**file->id** is the id if file that you can use it as entity reference target_id (I mean file field).

and a good example how save and attach file to Node

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

// Create file object from remote URL.
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon.small_.png');
$file = file_save_data($data, 'public://druplicon.png', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

// Create node object with attached file.
$node = Node::create([
  'type'        => 'article',
  'title'       => 'Druplicon test',
  'field_image' => [
    'target_id' => $file->id(),
  ],
]);
$node->save();
```

What if the file is already present in your local file system and you want to attach it to an existing node? Here's an example for that too:

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use \Drupal\file\Entity\File;

// Create file object from a locally copied file.
$uri  = file_unmanaged_copy('public://source.jpg', 'public://destination.jpg', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
$file = File::Create([
  'uri' => $uri,
]);
$file->save();

// Load existing node and attach file.
$node = Node::load(1);
$node->field_image->setValue([
  'target_id' => $file->id(),
]);
$node->save();
```

And lastly, what if you want to stick a placeholder file to a node? Thanks to Drupal 8, this is too easy:

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node = Node::create([
  'type'  => 'article',
  'title' => 'Generated image test',
]);
$node->field_image->generateSampleItems();
$node->save();
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `$file->id()`?

Answer (score 1):

[file_save_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_save_data/8.2.x) returns a file object on a successful save. That object must be an instance of [FileInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21FileInterface.php/interface/FileInterface/8.2.x).

As such, then you can just do:

`$fid = $filesaved->id();`

Answer (score 1):

The function  `file_save_data()` returns a file entity. So i suppose you need `$filesaved->fid->value`. And `$filesaved->id()` returns the same result.